# How do I convert an interval into a number of hours with postgres?

Tags: datetime, postgresql, intervals

Say I have an interval like

```
4 days 10:00:00
```

in postgres. How do I convert that to a number of hours (106 in this case?) Is there a function or should I bite the bullet and do something like

```
extract(days, my_interval) * 24 + extract(hours, my_interval)
```

Comment: Note: If your interval contains months or years, there is no defined answer of how many hours there are, since the number of days in a month or year vary.  So watch out for that!

Comment: @Teddy: More precisely, there are _multiple_ defined answers ;)

Answer (score 469, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(epoch FROM my_interval)/3600
```

Comment: And maybe floor or cast the result to integer if the interval contains minutes and/or seconds

Comment: Extract epoch? Oh my, that wouldn't have crossed my mind in a million years.

Comment: SELECT EXTRACT(epoch FROM my_interval/3600)

(interval has native 'divide integer' support, result is interval, and extract result is integer, not float). So. Autocast/Floor done.

Comment: Warning: simply extracting epoch implicitly assumes that one month = 30 days and one year = 365.25 days.

Comment: @Teddy what can we do with it? How to avoid this issue and get real number of epochs?

Comment: @Asmox, where is the problem ? This is used for duration. `select extract(epoch from timestamp '2020-10-31 23:59:59' - timestamp '2020-10-01 00:00:00')` gives 2678399 as does `select extract(epoch from interval '1 month 23:59:59')`.

Comment: Just found a problem with this approach. It doesn't take into consideration of leap years so it's always a few days less if you are doing a long interval like 10 years.

Comment: @ZZCoder Calculations with Date and time are more complicated than people think: A century can be 36525 or 36524 days, a month 28-31 days, a minute 59-61 seconds. And this without taking into account time zones (which can be plus or minus hours and 0, 15, 30 or 45 minutes, and some change the offset twice a year, the rules for when this happens can change, and which time zone applies can change at any time). My advice is: don't do calculations in seconds if seconds aren't the goal.

Comment: @ZZCoder This approach just takes an interval (a duration of time) and tells you how many hours that interval is. Intervals are independent of leap years. If you're having a problem with leap years, the problem is somewhere else, outside the scope of this answer.

Comment: Another example for this function that will convert interval to second as integer without round function.
`SELECT ROUND(EXTRACT(epoch FROM '00:00:59.743685'::interval))`

Answer (score 39):

If you want integer i.e. number of days:

```
SELECT (EXTRACT(epoch FROM (SELECT (NOW() - '2014-08-02 08:10:56')))/86400)::int
```

Comment: Great! Thank you for that :) Yet, I found that we can now modify this to be `SELECT extract('epoch' FROM age('2014-08-02'::timestamp)) / 86400` (I'm using Pg 9.4), since `age(ts)` automatically use `CURRENT_DATE` when only one argument.

Comment: Warning: simply extracting epoch implicitly assumes that one month = 30 days and one year = 365.25 days.

Answer (score 11):

To get the number of days the easiest way would be:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM NOW() - '2014-08-02 08:10:56');
```

As far as I know it would return the same as:

```
SELECT (EXTRACT(epoch FROM (SELECT (NOW() - '2014-08-02 08:10:56')))/86400)::int;
```

Comment: If your interval is `'1 month 0 days'`, using `extract(day from …)` will give you `0` as the result.

Answer (score 3):

```
select floor((date_part('epoch', order_time - '2016-09-05 00:00:00') / 3600)), count(*)
from od_a_week
group by floor((date_part('epoch', order_time - '2016-09-05 00:00:00') / 3600));
```

The `::int` conversion follows the principle of rounding.
If you want a different result such as rounding down, you can use the corresponding math function such as `floor`.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert table field:

1. Define the field so it contains seconds:

   ```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
        ...
        field        INTERVAL SECOND(0)
    );
   ```
2. Extract the value. **Remember to cast to int** other wise you can get an unpleasant surprise once the intervals are big:

   `EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM field)::int`

Comment: I don't think Redshift supports the INTERVAL datatype. It would just be BIGINT.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display your result only in date type after adding the interval then, should try this

Select (current_date + interval 'x day')::date;

Answer (score 0):

A function to avoid having verbose `extract epoch` all over the place. Returns seconds so for hours needs `int_interval('1 day') / 3600`

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION int_interval(interval_text text) returns INT LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE as $$ SELECT EXTRACT(epoch FROM interval_text::INTERVAL)::INT $$;
```

Usage

```sql
int_interval('1 day')
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm working with PostgreSQL 11, and I created a function to get the hours betweeen 2 differents timestamps

```
create function analysis.calcHours(datetime1 timestamp, datetime2 timestamp)
    returns integer
    language plpgsql as $$
    declare
        diff interval;
    begin
        diff = datetime2 - datetime1;
        return (abs(extract(days from diff))*24 + abs(extract(hours from diff)))::integer;
    end; $$;
```

Answer (score -4):

```
         select date 'now()' - date '1955-12-15';
```

Here is the simple query which calculates total no of days.

Comment: That does not take an interval value.