# Date difference in days in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I am trying to calculate the difference between dates in days.
Datatype is Text for columns snapshot_date and date_opened.I am getting an  ERROR: function date_part(unknown, integer) does not exist

```
SELECT DATE_PART('day', snapshot_date::date -date_opened::date)::number from my_table
```

Comment: Check the similar thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17833176/postgresql-days-months-years-between-two-dates

Comment: "Datatype is Text for columns snapshot_date and date_opened" -- Fix this and use a date type like `date` or `timestamp`.

Comment: What is your postgreSQL version?

Comment: **Never** store date values in a `text` (or `varchar`)  column. Doing that is a really, really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#OPERATORS-DATETIME-TABLE) subtracting one date from the other returns an integer representing the number of days, so:

```
snapshot_date::date - date_opened::date
```

is all you need.

This assumes that both columns can safely be cast to a `date`.