# Convert interval to number in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, types, type-conversion

I have created a query which sums up the interval for respective date-time,

```
select sum(ts_polling) / count(ts_polling) as Average_Queue_Wait_Time ,  cast(time_start AS Date)
  from callcent_queuecalls group by cast(time_start AS date) order by time_start DESC;
```

[image]

Is there a way to convert Average_Queue_Wait_Time from interval data type to number ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952493/how-do-i-convert-an-interval-into-a-number-of-hours-with-postgres , You can check this.

Comment: what number it is ?.. number of seconds?.. hours?..

Comment: I want to convert avergae_queue_wait_time to integer value.
I tried using extract function as follows,


`SELECT EXTRACT(second FROM (select sum(ts_polling) / count(ts_polling)
  from callcent_queuecalls group by cast(time_start AS date) )) AS Queue_Wait_Time, 
cast(time_start AS DATE) AS DayOfMonth from callcent_queuecalls group by cast(time_start AS Date) order by cast(time_start AS DATE) DESC`
----------

the following error was returned, 



********** Error **********



_ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
SQL state: 2100_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the number of seconds in an interval like this:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(epoch FROM INTERVAL '1 day 30 minutes 1.234 seconds');

┌───────────┐
│ date_part │
├───────────┤
│ 88201.234 │
└───────────┘
(1 row)
```

Comment: Is it possible to extract on a subquery ? For instance I ran the following statement and resulted in error  `SELECT EXTRACT(second FROM (select sum(ts_polling) / count(ts_polling)
  from callcent_queuecalls group by cast(time_start AS date) )) AS Queue_Wait_Time, 
cast(time_start AS DATE) AS DayOfMonth from callcent_queuecalls group by cast(time_start AS Date) order by cast(time_start AS DATE) DESC 
`

_ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression SQL state: 2100_

Comment: You can only use such a subselect if it returns at most one row. You should use `SELECT EXTRACT(second FROM sum(ts_polling) / count(ts_polling)) FROM ...`.

Comment: Excellent ! This gave me exactly the output I was looking for. I used this query in metabase dashboard and it looks awesome. Thank you for the help... Cheers