# I want to covert interval to decimal in postgres and need this result?

Tags: postgresql, datetime, intervals

Hi i have same query in oracle

```
select ( TRUNC(b.pub_ts, 'MI') - DATE '1970-01-01')* 24 * 60 * 60, 
             TRUNC(b.pub_ts, 'MI') - DATE '1970-01-01'
                from abctable b  where b.blurb_id=344143
```

the output of query in oracle is this

[image]

and i have converted query in postgres and i want same result how can i get that , i have created the query for postgres but it is giveing interval not decimal output like oracle

```
 select  ( date_trunc('minute', b.pub_ts) - DATE '1970-01-01')* 24 * 60 * 60,
                              date_trunc('minute', b.pub_ts) - DATE '1970-01-01'
  FROM abc b WHERE b.blurb_id=344143;
```

[image]

I have tried many solution . can you help me out.

Comment: no this will not give the output i want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [are](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2081375/are) is right, I think it is a duplicate of [How do I convert an interval into a number of hours with postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952493/how-do-i-convert-an-interval-into-a-number-of-hours-with-postgres)

If you check the accepted answer, the only thing different in the example below is, I added a division of 24.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(epoch FROM INTERVAL '1499990400 days 1206720:00:00')/24/60/60,
       EXTRACT(epoch FROM INTERVAL '17361 days 13:58:00')/24/60/60;
```

returns

1500040680 and 17361.581944444442

which are exactly the values you want.

Your query should look along the lines of this:

```
SELECT
  extract( epoch FROM date_trunc('minute', b.pub_ts) - DATE '1970-01-01'),
  extract( epoch FROM date_trunc('minute', b.pub_ts) - DATE '1970-01-01')/86400
FROM abc b WHERE b.blurb_id=344143;
```

Comment: This is perfect solution.