# Transform days into hours in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have  Hours,Minute,Second, and days as results in the Postgres query. I want to convert everything into hours.

Example

```
Row 1 result: 19:53:45
Row 2 result: 1 day 05:41:58
```

Now I want to convert days into hours like below

```
   Row 1 result:19:53:45
    Row 2 result: 29:41:58
```

Can someone help me how to do it in the postgres sql?

Comment: What data type is that column?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert an interval into a number of hours with postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952493/how-do-i-convert-an-interval-into-a-number-of-hours-with-postgres)

Comment: I'd try `cast(col as interval hour to minute)`.

Comment: @jarlh: that doesn't change anything: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5bfe94f0b3b9a3ca07c57da8692dfcc6

Answer (score 1):

`cast(col as interval hour to minute)` should work, according to Standard SQL.

Anyway, this seems to work:

```
col - extract(day from col) * interval '1'  day  -- remove the days 
    + extract(day from col) * interval '24' hour -- and add back as hours
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9ccd368103eddcf08073495c973f5c98)

Comment: It is working fine for 1 day. my row results may have n days. could you help me to cover all day scenarios? ex 2 days, 10 days, etc.

Comment: It's working for any number of days, at least in my fiddle. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want the result as a string, because times are limited to 24 hours.  You can construct it as:

```
select *,
       (case when ar[1] like '%day%'
             then (split_part(col, ' ', 1)::int * 24 + split_part(ar[1], ' ', 3)::int)::text ||
                  right(col, 6)
             else col
        end)
from (values ('19:53:45'), ('1 day 05:41:58')) v(col) cross join lateral
     regexp_split_to_array(col, ':') a(ar);
```

You can also do this without `a`:

```
select *, 
       (case when col like '%day%'
             then (split_part(col, ' ', 1)::int * 24 + (regexp_match(col, ' ([0-9]+):'))[1]::int)::text ||
                  right(col, 6)
             else col
        end)
from (values ('19:53:45'), ('1 day 05:41:58')) v(col) ;
```

Comment: It is working fine for 1 day. my row results may have n days. could you help me to cover all day scenarios? ex 2 days, 10 days, etc.

Comment: @user3614760 . . . These do cover any number of days, so I don't understand your comment.