# How to validate and/or convert SQL interval string in python?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

There are many different ways to specify an interval in SQL. Specifically, in PostgreSQL flavour, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html.

Is there a way to validate an arbitrary interval string in Python? Is there a way to convert it into a `timedelta`? Can it be done without an explicit connection (and a call to the cursor)?

For some simple string like `31 minutes` I could write a custom validator which splits on space and validates that we have an integer and valid units. But what about strings like `1 year 2 months 3 days 4 hours 5 minutes 6 seconds`, `P1Y2M3DT4H5M6S`, `P0001-02-03T04:05:06`? I don't want to write my own validators for them all, so is there a better way?

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/952600/10309040?

Comment: Yes, and according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/8980982/7978198, "SQLAlchemy doesn't build this in as it defers to the DBAPI/database as the best and most efficient source of validation and coercion of values." So it appears doing it via the database is the correct way to do it generally.