# Extracting epoch from two different days yields same result

Tags: postgresql, datetime, epoch

If I run this query on my database

```
SELECT EXTRACT('epoch' FROM age('2021-01-01'::date, '2019-12-01'::date))
```

The result is `34149600`.

But then if I try with 2019-12-02 (one day more)

```
SELECT EXTRACT('epoch' FROM age('2021-01-01'::date, '2019-12-02'::date))
```

The result is exactly the same `34149600`!

As if the seconds passed from 02 december 2019  to 01 january 2021 are the same as the seconds passed from 01 december 2019 to 01 january 2021.

Why is this? I've already tried the above code with timezones on 00:00:00+00 timezone for all dates (for 1st january 2021, 1st december 2019 and 2nd december 2021), and it gives the same result

Obviously, I would have expected the epoch to be different, around 3600*24 of difference (seconds in a day).

Comment: [This](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=523cc7ed893a03b1107fce22bbd34fa1) should give you a hint. See also [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952493/how-do-i-convert-an-interval-into-a-number-of-hours-with-postgres#comment77606009_952600)

Comment: I think it is related to how a month and 30 days are interpreted as same. I mean,, one of them is '1 year 1 mon' and the other is '1 year 30 days'. Strip year and think '1 mon' and '30 days' converted to seconds. Wouldn't you expect the same 30 * 86400? IOW what should '1 mon' be treated as in terms of days.

Comment: You can calculate the difference in days: `'2021-01-01'::date - '2019-12-01'::date` yields `397` and `'2021-01-01'::date - '2019-12-02'::date` yields `396`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The similar results come from the `age()` function which returns an interval with years, months, days. In such an interval, 1 month = 30 days, so their conversions in seconds are similar.

You will get the expected result with

```
SELECT extract(epoch from  ('2021-01-01'::timestamp - '2019-12-01'::timestamp)) => 34300800.000000
SELECT extract(epoch from  ('2021-01-01'::timestamp - '2019-12-02'::timestamp)) => 34214400.000000
```